# Custom table view scrolling animation

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitableview

In my app I'm trying to implement custom table view scrolling. I'm trying to achieve something similar to [Volvo ocean race app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/volvo-ocean-race-2014-15/id915466522?mt=8), which does it very well.

Basically when user scrolls, middle cell gets higher and current high cell gets smaller

[image: volvo ocean race app]

My original idea was playing with cell's frame in `scrollViewDidScroll` method for example

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if(self.tblViewPhotos.contentOffset.y > 0)
    {
        var thisCell = self.tblViewPhotos.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath) as PhotoCell
        var offset = self.tblViewPhotos.contentOffset.y;
        thisCell.frame = CGRectMake(thisCell.frame.origin.x, thisCell.frame.origin.y, thisCell.frame.size.width, 250-offset);
    }
}
```

however I'm getting very buggy results (frame changing suddenly when swiping fast etc). I would be glad, if someone can point me to right direction